# Dronekit Python - Is it possible to send commands from Nodejs?

Tags: python, node.js, dronekit

I'm trying to use Dronekit Python 2 for creating a minimalistic GCS (ground station). From the examples it looks like python scripts always finish and the connection with the vehicle is lost. That said, Is there any way to code a python script that works like a thread and only exit once it get's a command from Nodejs? Nodejs has the python-shell module that is supposed to send messages to python via STDIN. So my goal is to run python script from Nodejs python-shell, and then send commands to dronekit (connect, arm, takeoff, etc). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can build your GUI in nodejs and use UDP or websocket to communicate with python code, where you build a dronekit wrapped with UDP or websocket.